# Neo4j，How to return nodes and relations where pathes between two nodes more than one

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

Create sample data, Actually data has 50 thousand Persons, 10 thousand Company.

```
CREATE(p1:Person{name:"p1"})
CREATE(p2:Person{name:"p2"})
CREATE(p3:Person{name:"p3"})
CREATE(c1:Company{name:"c1"})
CREATE(c2:Company{name:"c2"})
CREATE (p1)-[:STAFF]->(c1)
CREATE (p1)-[:STAFF]->(c2)
CREATE (p2)-[:STAFF]->(c1)
CREATE (p2)-[:STAFF]->(c2)
CREATE (p3)-[:STAFF]->(c1)
```

I want to find nodes and relations where paths between two person nodes more than one, in this example(p1,p2).
I try to query with [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68650383/return-paths-to-nodes-with-more-than-n-relationships), but it is very slowly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try this:

```
MATCH path=(p1:Person)-[:STAFF]->(c:Company)<-[:STAFF]-(p2:Person)
WHERE id(p1) > id(p2)
WITH p1,p2, COLLECT(path) AS paths
WHERE SIZE(paths) > 1
RETURN paths
```